# null check operator used on a null value error when I try to go to signup screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error when I run my flutter app:

```
Null check operator used on a null value
```

my main.dart code:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initialServices();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LocalController controller= Get.put(LocalController());
    return GetMaterialApp(
      translations: MyTranslation(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      locale: controller.language,
      theme: controller.appTheme,
      
      initialBinding: InitialBindings(),
      getPages: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

login. dart, note that the error occurs when I press on signup -I've put a comment where the button is- :

```
class Login extends StatelessWidget{
  const Login({Key?key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LoginControllerImp controller = Get.put(LoginControllerImp());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("3".tr,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge!.copyWith(color: AppColor.grey),
        ),
        backgroundColor: AppColor.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body:  WillPopScope(
        onWillPop:()=> alertExitApp(),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15,horizontal: 35),
          child: Form(
            key: controller.formstate,
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                const LogoAuth(),
                const CustomTextTitleAuth(text: "2",),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                const CustomTextBodyAuth(text: "4",),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),

                CustomTextFormAuth(
                  isNumber: false,
                  valid: (val) {
                    return validInput(val!, 5, 100, "email");
                  },
                  mycontroller: controller?.email ?? TextEditingController(),
                  hinttext: "6",
                  labeltext: "5",
                  iconData: Icons.email_outlined,
                ),
                GetBuilder<LoginControllerImp>(
                  builder: (controller) => CustomTextFormAuth(
                    isNumber: false,
                    valid: (val) {
                      return validInput(val!, 5, 30, "password");
                    },
                    isPassword: controller?.isShowPassword ?? false,
                    onTapIcon: () {
                      controller?.showPassword();
                    },
                    mycontroller: controller?.password ?? TextEditingController(),
                    hinttext: "8",
                    labeltext: "7",
                    iconData: controller?.isShowPassword == true ? Icons.key_off_rounded : Icons.key,
                  ),
                ),


                InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      controller.goForgetPassword();
                    },
                    child: Text("9".tr, textAlign: TextAlign.end,)),

                CustomButtonAuth(
                  text: "21".tr,
                  onPressed: (){
                    controller.login();
                  },),

                const SizedBox(height: 30,),
                CustomTextSignUpOrSignIn(
                  text1: "10",
                  text2: "11", //signup 
                  onTap: (){
                    controller.goToSignUp();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

}
```

signup.dart:

```
class SignUp extends StatelessWidget{
  const SignUp({Key?key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("21".tr,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge!.copyWith(color: AppColor.grey),
        ),
        backgroundColor: AppColor.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body:WillPopScope(
    onWillPop:()=> alertExitApp(),
    child: GetBuilder<SignUpControllerImp>(
        builder:(controller) => Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15,horizontal: 35),
          child: Form(
            key: controller.formstate,
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                const CustomTextTitleAuth(text: "2",),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                const CustomTextBodyAuth(text: "4",),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),

                CustomTextFormAuth(
                  isNumber: false,
                  valid: (val){
                    return validInput(val!, 3, 30, "username");
                  },
                  mycontroller: controller.username,
                  hinttext: "22",
                  labeltext: "23",
                  iconData: Icons.person_2_outlined,
                ),

                CustomTextFormAuth(
                  isNumber: false,
                  valid: (val){
                    return validInput(val!, 5, 30, "email");
                  },
                  mycontroller: controller.email,
                  hinttext: "6",
                  labeltext: "5",
                  iconData: Icons.email_outlined,
                ),


                CustomTextFormAuth(
                  isNumber: true,
                  valid: (val){
                    return validInput(val!, 5, 30, "phone");
                  },
                  mycontroller: controller.phone,
                  hinttext: "24",
                  labeltext: "25",
                  iconData: Icons.phone_android_outlined,
                ),

                CustomTextFormAuth(
                  isNumber: false,
                  valid: (val){
                    return validInput(val!, 5, 30, "password");
                  },
                  isPassword: true,
                  mycontroller: controller.password,
                  hinttext: "8",
                  labeltext: "7",
                  iconData: Icons.lock_outline,
                ),


                CustomButtonAuth(
                  text: "11".tr,
                  onPressed: (){
                    controller.signUp();
                  },),

                const SizedBox(height: 30,),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text("26".tr),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: (){
                          controller.logIn();
                        },
                        child: Text("3".tr,
                          style:const TextStyle(
                            color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),),
                      )
                    ]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),),
    );
  }

}
```

this line:

```
 body:WillPopScope(
```

gave me this message:

`'WillPopScope' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use PopScope instead. This feature was deprecated after v3.12.0-1.0.pre. (Documentation)  Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.`

the trace of code:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device 220233L2G...
Restarted application in 4,375ms.
[GETX] Instance "MyServices" has been created
[GETX] Instance "MyServices" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "LocalController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "LocalController" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "Crud" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
[GETX] Redirect to RouteSettings("/login", null)
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /login
[GETX] Instance "LoginControllerImp" has been created
[GETX] Instance "LoginControllerImp" has been initialized
I/GED     ( 6846): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 2, oppidx_max 2, oppidx_min 0
[GETX] REPLACE ROUTE /login
[GETX] NEW ROUTE /signup

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building WillPopScope(dependencies: [_ModalScopeStatus], state: _WillPopScopeState#c6f6d):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  WillPopScope WillPopScope:file:///D:/steps/finalproject2/lib/view/screen/auth/signup.dart:28:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      GetBuilderState.initState (package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_state.dart:134:40)
#1      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5602:55)
#2      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
...     Normal element mounting (33 frames)
#35     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
#36     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6871:36)
#37     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6883:32)
...     Normal element mounting (330 frames)
#367    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
#368    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6871:36)
#369    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
#370    Element.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4024:32)
#371    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6896:17)
#372    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#373    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#374    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#375    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#376    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#377    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#378    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#379    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#380    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#381    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#382    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#383    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#384    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#385    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:105:11)
#386    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#387    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#388    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#389    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#390    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#391    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#392    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#393    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#394    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#395    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:105:11)
#396    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#397    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#398    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#399    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#400    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#401    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#402    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#403    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#404    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#405    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#406    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#407    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#408    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#409    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#410    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#411    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#412    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#413    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#414    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#415    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#416    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#417    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#418    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#419    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#420    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#421    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#422    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2895:19)
#423    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:984:21)
#424    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:457:5)
#425    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1325:15)
#426    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1255:9)
#427    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:5)
#428    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#429    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:383:5)
#430    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)
====================================================================================================
[GETX] "LoginControllerImp" onDelete() called
[GETX] "LoginControllerImp" deleted from memory
```

Comment: hello guys , it looks like no one here to help me!

Comment: provide the goToSignUp() method from your controller

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this `body:WillPopScope(` with

```
PopScope(
      onPopInvoked: (val) => alertExitApp(),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).